# What are some good (retro) symbols for magic/mana/energy?

Tags: art, gui

Much like a heart is used a lot for health and lives in old retro games...

[image: minecraft heart]

**...what would be a good icon to use for Energy, Mana and/or Magic points?**

Comment: A purple-blue flame.

Comment: Well, a _meter_ [██████▒▒▒]?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know of any particular icons, but I think the most important thing to keep in mind is that **players associate the colour blue with magic**. Thus, I don't think the icon actually matters, as long as you follow the basic convention of **red for health, blue for magic and green (or the less-used yellow) for a third metric** (usually stamina, but can be other things like in the case of *Eternal Darkness: Sanity's Requiem* where green stood for sanity).

Typical shapes include orbs, crystals, potions or runes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Green for Zelda (LttP, OoT, MM and WW)!

Comment: Using blue for magic is not a hard and fast rule, it very much depends on the color scheme of the game. Generally you can use any color as long as it makes sense in the given context and you're consistent.

Comment: @AlexAmes While I agree with you, the user asked for "a good icon to use for Energy, Mana and/or Magic points". Since this can be debated at length, I believe it is better to answer generically. In that case, my answer simply points out what _seems_ to be the convention. I acknowledge that there is no "rule", per se, but there seems to be an unspoken convention nonetheless :)

Comment: Giving a different color to the mana than usual might be also a good choice, as it differentiates your game from others. One example of this is Gemcraft (with orange mana-gems, tough its not a retro game).

Answer (score 9):

Magic and stuff. Orbs, staffs, scepters and green/purples came to my mind. Here's Some of it:

- A basic orb :

[image]

- Some Zelda style rupee (You could modify it to a suitable color)

[image]
[image]

- Basic staffs and scepters :

[image]
[image]

- Some potion :

[image]

And also green and purple fire.

Comment: Sources? Licenses?

Comment: @Jeff The Purple Orb's Mine.(Free to Copy). Rest of them from Piq (Creative Commons)

Answer (score 1):

Purple or green stars could work for magic. For energy, maybe some yellow lightning bolts. And for food (mana), you could use any food item and pixelate it. I would be able to give more advice as far as shapes if you could tell me the theme of your game :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest for mana a retro crystal like in the background of this pokemon game:

[image]